# Como agregar una class="btn btn-danger" de bootstrap en un @Html.ActionLink - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

En el `@Html.ActionLink` ya cree dos new, pero también quiero agregarle una `class="btn btn-danger"` de bootstrap, si agrego un tercer new por ejemplo:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Baja", "BajaLibro", "Home", 
        new { idLibro = item.IdLibro, }, 
        new { onclick = "return confirmation();" }, 
        new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
```

no me deja, me tira un error.
Por el momento en mi 
`@Html.ActionLink`lo tengo así y me funciona perfectamente:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Baja", "BajaLibro", "Home", 
        new { idLibro = item.IdLibro, }, 
        new { onclick = "return confirmation();" })
```

Entonces como puedo agregarle la `class="btn btn-danger"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **HtmlHelper** `@Html.ActionLink` de ASP.NET MVC, dispone de varias **sobrecargas** para su construcción.

En tu caso, tanto el evento **`onclick`** como la clase **`@class`**, deben ir **dentro del mismo objeto anónimo** **`htmlAttributes`** y en el lugar correspondiente en la lista de parámetros.

La construcción correcta para esta sobrecarga del método `ActionLink(...)`, sería la siguiente:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Baja", "BajaLibro", "Home",
       new { idLibro = item.IdLibro }, 
       new { onclick = "return confirmation();", @class = "btn btn-danger" })
```

Comment: Gracias @Rafael Acosta funciona perfectamente!

Comment: Si ahí lo acabo de hacer muchas gracias!